# How to implement a current controlled voltage source, or a comparator that trips once a certain current is reached?

Tags: current, comparator, current-limiting

I have current flowing through a CCVS, once 10A is reached, the CCVS puts out 10V, which takes a comparator's output high. The current that goes through the CCVS continuous to the load. Is there a way to implement this without an ideal CCVS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure the voltage drop across a small (very small) resistor in series with the load using an instrumentation amplifier, and feed the output of the inamp into your comparator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkn67h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>